# Ugly fonts in Unity app on Windows 10

Tags: unity

I downloaded and installed Unity3D Personal edition on my Windows 10 computer and first time I launched it I couldn't help but notice that text looks really bad across all UI elements (buttons, dropdowns, preferences, etc) except system menus, as if anti-aliasing is turned off everywhere.

[image: Screenshot]

I couldn't find any settings related to this in Preferences. Is it GUI font customizable in Unity?

Comment: Did you install 32 bit or 64? I had the same issue installing the 32 bit version.

Comment: @Ryanwhite 64-bit

Comment: Ok i just loaded up unity 5 on my work laptop using windows 10. Mine looks like yours. Ill do some research and messing around and get back to you

Comment: I know recent versions of Windows apply some UI scaling on high-resolution displays - I had to disable it on my Surface to work at native resolution. Have you checked whether this is currently enabled? You can turn it off selectively for each program you want to use the native res, or system-wide.

Comment: Last time I checked, Unity didn't support high DPI displays properly and fonts became ugly.

Comment: I wouldn't call my monitor high DPI, it's just an ordinary 1680x1050 monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the dark theme, it makes the ugly Editor UI font more bearable.

If you compare my screenshot below with yours, you'll see that characters such as "C", "a" and "G" looks less broken in the dark theme.

[image]

yes you can turn on dark theme for personal edition with a bit (literally) of effort, just google for it.

Comment: Could you add the instructions for enabling dark theme here?

Comment: nope sorry my original answer included a youtube link describing how to enable the dark ui theme for unity personal edition was deleted because of it. The video showed how to use do it easily with HxD for all recent versions